# Could someone provide a list of all Buddhist schools?

Tags: traditions, teaching

If someone could provide a list of all Buddhist schools (both extinct and extant) it would be much appreciated. If this is unmanageable due to the high number, major schools would be good, or a link to such a list would be great. Thank you

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Out of thousands schools, sub-schools, and hybrids, here are some of the most notable outlines:

### Early Buddhism and conservative descendants

- =======Popular wing=======

  - **Mahasanghika (developed into Mahayana)**

    - Gokulika (*in Varanasi/Pataliputra*)

      - Bahusrutiya (*in Kosala*)

        - Satyasiddhi / Tattvasiddhi (Chinese, extinct)

          - Jojitsu (Japanese)
      - Prajnaptivada (*in Magadha*)
    - Lokottaravada
    - Caitika
  - Pudgalavada heresy (extinct)

    - Vatsiputriya (extinct)

      - Sanmitiya (extinct)
- =======Conservative center=======

  - Tamraparniya (the Sri Lanka offshoot)

    - **Theravada**
  - Mahisasaka (absorbed into Theravada)
  - Dharmaguptaka (in Gandhara, extinct)

    - Ritsu (Japanese)
- =======Abhidharma wing=======

  - Sarvastivada (in Gandhara, extinct)

    - Vaibhashika (extinct)
    - **Sautrantika (developed into Yogacara)**
    - Kusha (Japanese, extinct)

### Mahayana

- =======Prajnaparamita / emptiness group=======

  - Yogacara line

    - Faxiang (Chinese)
    - Hosso (Japanese)
  - Madhyamaka line

    - Tibetan family

      - Kadam (extinct)

        - **Gelug (Dalai Lama's school)**
      - Sakya
    - Sanlun (Chinese, extinct)

      - Sanron (Japanese, extinct)
  - Chan (Chinese)

    - **Zen (Japanese)**

      - Soto
      - Rinzai

        - Fuke (extinct)
      - Obaku
    - Seon (Korean)

      - **Jogye / Chogye (my Zen Master's school)**
    - Thien (Vietnamese)
- =======Tantric group=======

  - Tibetan tantra

    - Nyingma

      - Aro gTér
    - Kagyu

      - **Karma-Kagyu (Chogyam Trungpa's school)**
    - New Kadampa (Gelug breakaway)
  - Tangmi (Chinese)

    - Shingon (Japanese)
- =======Sincretic group=======

  - Bon-Nyingma hybrid (Tibetan)
  - Shugendo (Japanese)
  - Ari Gaing (Burma, extinct)
  - Newar (Nepal)
- =======Popular wing / Ekayana=======

  - Pure Land / Amitabha line

    - Jodo (Japanese)
    - Yuzu Nembutsu (Japanese)
  - Lotus Sutra line

    - Tiantai (Chinese)

      - Cheontae (Korean)
      - Tendai (Japanese)
      - Nichiren (Japanese)

        - **Nipponzan-Myohoji (my first encounter with Buddhism)**
  - Avatamsaka Sutra line

    - Huayan (Chinese)

      - Kegon (Japanese)
      - Hwaeom (Korean, subsumed by Seon)

Answer (score 7):

There are the following links to Buddhist Schools:

- Wikipedia - [*"Schools of Buddhism"*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schools_of_Buddhism).
- BuddhaNet - [*"Schools / Lineages"*](http://www.buddhanet.net/e-learning/history/schools.htm).
- Rigpawiki - [*"The four main schools of Tibetan Buddhism"*](http://www.rigpawiki.org/index.php?title=The_four_main_schools_of_Tibetan_Buddhism)
- DharmaNet - [*"The Principal Spiritual Traditions of Buddhism"*](http://www.dharmanet.org/traditionsbasicdn.htm)
- Budsas [*"Two Main Schools of Buddhism"*](http://www.budsas.org/ebud/whatbudbeliev/59.htm)
- [*"History & Timeline of Buddhism’s Spread"*](http://www.onmarkproductions.com/html/schools-three-vehicles.shtml)
- SiddhartaBuddhism - [*"Buddhist Sects"*](http://siddharthabhuddhism.weebly.com/5-different-sects-of-buddhism.html)
- [*"Schools of Buddhism and their countries: An overview"*](http://www.bloomingrosepress.com/BuddhistTraditions.html)