# How many types of Buddhism are there?

Tags: philosophy, teaching

And what is the main differences between them?  Is it like Christianity where there seems to be a couple of main ones and then dozens of smaller ones doing their own thing?

Comment: There have been several attempts before, to ask this question. I think it's probably better to link to some of those, than to ask another question on the same topic -- unless you want to make this question more specific somehow (to distinguish it from previous questions).

Comment: Also see [Could someone provide a list of all Buddhist schools?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/10412/could-someone-provide-a-list-of-all-buddhist-schools)